# Built-in camera not working on Ubuntu 20.04 installed on Macbook pro late 2013

Tags: macbook, gpu-driver, cheese

I have tried all the existing suggestions (including iSight, cheese) I could find on this and other forums to make the camera work, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the error message from cheese:

```
: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

Does anyone know if there is any update regarding the camera issue for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Does [this driver from patjak](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started) not work for you? I’ve been using it without problem for a couple of years on different MacBooks, but don’t have a 2013 model to test with 

Comment: Please correct & clarify your release details.  Ubuntu has used *year* only format for *snap* only releases since 2016, ie. do you mean you're using Ubuntu Core 20, as that's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.   You've also tagged 14.04 so how does that relate?  Please clarify.   (FYI:  on macbook you normally install a *yy.mm* release; `cheese` implies to me a desktop is wanted, and Ubuntu releases using *yy* are intended for headless operation, even though GNOME can be installed on them - it's not the same as a desktop release)